# How can I upgrade this bower require statement to webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bower, require

I'm working on some old project written in JS and Backbone, and we're trying to move from grunt and bower towards webpack. In some files there is used this kind of require which doesnt work anymore:

```
require([
"someComponentA",
"someComponentB",
"someComponentC"], function(A, B, C) {

})
```

Is there any way to replace this part of code with something else?

edit
The point is we want to get rid of requirejs. Problem occurs when I'm trying to launch e2e tests, because they work on files and not on links. So i assume they're fired by browser and not by NodeJS, that's why in console i see require is not defined.

Comment: Read about AMD: https://www.jvandemo.com/a-10-minute-primer-to-javascript-modules-module-formats-module-loaders-and-module-bundlers/

Comment: The point is we want to get rid of requirejs. Problem occurs when I'm trying to launch e2e tests, because they work on files and not on links. So i assume they're fired by browser and not by NodeJS, that's why in console i see require is not defined.